# how to retrieve all the data of a table and duplicate it in another table with ETL Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pdi

i am using pentaho data integration and I would like to generate or duplicate the data from one table input for another table output in pdi with ETL[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgsSG.png)

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate. Can you please share your sample input data and expected data. Or share your transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you want to load the table B with exactly the same data in Table A twice or n times. The easiest way would be to create two transformations and a job calling the transformations.

- The first transformation generates n rows (the number of rows you want the data repeated) with a simple *Data generator* step, after the data generator, you put a *Copy rows to result* step
- The second transformation simply querys table A with a *Table input* step and inserts that data in table B with a *Table output* step.
- Then you create a job with two *Transformation* job entries. The first transformation, and the second transformation. In the second transformation properties, you check the option *Execute for every input row?* so the transformation is executed the number of rows generated in the first transformation.

You have in the installation directory of PDI a samples directory, inside there's a *jobs/shell for every row/* with an example of how to execute a job entry n times.

If you only want to duplicate the rows, I wouldn't bother creating the first transformation, I would simply create the first transformation and call it twice in the job. It's not so elegant, but it's quicker if n is small, it's not going to change with time and you don't need to reuse it in another process.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked this question at least twice, without giving much detail. Do you want something like this:

```
Table A:
COLUMN1|COLUMN2
A|B
C|D

Table B:
COLUMN1|COLUMN2
A|B
A|B
C|D
C|D
```

In that case, the easiest way would be to create a transformation Table Input A -> Table Output B, and calling that transformation twice in a job.